# Visual Studio Installer Projects Extension - Install a Service

Tags: c#, service, windows-installer

I'm using the Visual Studio Installer Projects Extension to create a .msi for my project.

The installer seems to work ok for the most part, but it won't kick off my service after install and I have to run MyService.exe manually.

Is there a way to do this? Or could I inject some custom installer code somewhere?

Comment: You mean MSI is getting installed successfully but the service doesn't get started always? or sometimes it fails to start ?

Comment: So the extension creates all the install folders and copies the required files which is great. It doesn't however register my service (not listed under services.msc). I've now created a service installer class, but not sure how if at all I can use that with the extension

Comment: Thats the right way to go. you should create a service installer class and add the project where the class resides as primary out put to the installer project then add the primary output to custom actions.(install/commit/uninstall)

Answer (score 1):

Viusal Studio Installer projects don't expose Windows Installer's underlying ServiceInstall / ServiceControl tables.  This forces developers to reinvent the wheel using custom actions resulting in fragile installers.

Windows Installer XML can author merge modules that properly implement ServiceInstall / Service Control.  You can then reference that merge module into your Visual Studio Installer to accomplish the task with breaking best practices.  A discussion of this can be found here:

[Augmenting InstallShield using Windows Installer XML - Windows Services](http://blog.iswix.com/2011/01/augmenting-installshield-using-windows.html)

[Redemption of Visual Studio Deployment Projects](http://blog.deploymentengineering.com/2011/03/redemption-of-visual-studio-deployment.html)

[IsWiX Tutorials](https://github.com/iswix-llc/iswix-tutorials) - How to author a Windows Service using WiX / IsWiX

Comment: Gathering up some [limitations of Visual Studio Installer projects](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47944893/129130). Heresy that redemption piece of yours :-). Plus one.

Comment: I wasted a year of my life that I'll never get back working with that crappy tool.

Comment: "File-pushers-anonymous". That would be us? [Chicks dig it](https://twitter.com/glytzhkof/status/1011193027585564672)!

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft has described the process of creating a service installer in this MSDN article: [How to: Add Installers to Your Service Application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ddhy0byf(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Ok cool thanks. So will that build an installer when i build the entire project?

Answer (score 0):

See if this helps:

http://www.installsite.org/pages/en/msi/tips.htm

Scroll down to Installing Services with Visual Studio.

It's a tool for adding the ServiceInstall/ServiceControl features to a VS setup. I haven't updated it for a while but all the source is there.