# How do I create an .msi or setup.exe from VS 2017

Tags: windows-installer, visual-studio-setup-proje

I am trying to create an installation package for a WPF desktop application. I have installed the Visual Studio Installer and wanted to use the Setup Wizard. It only seems to create MSM or CAB installations. I really want an .msi or setup.exe as the output. Is that possible with the MS Visual Studio Installer or must I add a different tool?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can indeed create MSI files with the [Visual Studio Installer Project type](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioProductTeam.MicrosoftVisualStudio2017InstallerProjects) in Visual Studio 2017, but the whole tool is not recommended due to [a number of significant limitations](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47944893/129130).

If you insist on using this project type then you simply create a "**Setup Project**" like this and you should be able to compile MSI files.

[image: Setup Project]

I will try to send you to two previous answers with more details on alternatives:

- [**Simplified MSI Tools List**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50225031/windows-service-not-shown-in-add-remove-programs-under-control-panel/50229840#50229840)
- **[How to create windows installer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49624070/how-to-create-windows-installer/49632260#49632260)**

All the tools listed above will do a good job of creating an MSI file.

Answer (score -1):

You should use a Setup Project type, not the wizard. That will give you an IDE into a Windows Installer MSI build. Although this is old these projects haven't changed for years:

https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/dotnet/visual-studio/getting-started-with-setup-projects/

You really only need a setup.exe if your setup needs to install prerequisites, which it will do before installing the MSI file that's also created.