# how to build new version of exe using Microsoft Visual Studio Installer Projects

Tags: windows-installer, installation, setup-deployment, vsinstaller

I use **Microsoft Visual Studio Installer Projects**. The first time I create my setup file, but then after I publish my MSI, I  did some updates to my application and I tried to re-build it, but it won't create a new MSI. Can someone please help me?

Answer (score 1):

***Errors***: Please describe any error messages you see. Maybe use screenshots? (sparingly).

***Basics***: I don't use Visual Studio installer projects due to [a number of limitations they suffer from](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47936435/visual-studio-publish-project-into-one-simple-installer/47944893#47944893) (some degree of subjectivity there). However, you generally need to change some GUIDs such as **product code** and bump up the **ProductVersion** to set up a Windows Installer major upgrade when you want to upgrade your application.

***Links***: Here are some old, but hopefully helpful links (most from MSI expert **Phil Wilson**):

- [**Updates to setup projects**](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/dotnet/visual-studio/updates-to-setup-projects/)
- [Getting Started With Setup Projects](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/dotnet/visual-studio/getting-started-with-setup-projects/)
- [Troubleshooting Setup and Deployment Projects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2010/kz0ke5xt(v%3Dvs.100))