# Programmatically Set VS Installer Project Version on Build Action

Tags: c#, build, windows-installer

I have a C# WPF application, which is written in Visual Studio 2017 (15.9.9) using .Net 4.7. The solution for the application contains two projects - the WPF Project itself and also a [Microsoft VS Installer Project](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=visualstudioclient.MicrosoftVisualStudio2017InstallerProjects) that creates a .msi file on the build action.

I have stored the version information for the application project and can return it using the following method

```
public static string GetVersion()
{
    try
    {
        System.Reflection.Assembly assembly = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
        FileVersionInfo fvi = FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo(assembly.Location);
        string version = fvi.FileVersion;
        return $"Version {version}";
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        //send error notif to IT dept.
        Alert_IT(ex, GetCurrentMethod(), false);
        return "0";
    }
}
```

I would like to use the result of this to set the the version information in the Setup project when I build the solution - at the moment it has to be manually entered into the properties of the setup project.

Since we are planning on using setup projects for all our applications, it would be really nice to only have to alter the version in one place for all our projects, ensuring that there are no inconsistencies.

Is it possible to set the version on a setup project programmatically? It would have to be done before the .msi is created.

If this is not possible, do you have any other suggestions as to how to achieve the desired outcome - that the version information for the application need only be set in one place before it is built?

I have seen the advice [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/22052ccb-a7a6-4240-af6c-c65ba8ee95d7/give-version-number-for-a-setup-project-programmatically), but did not find it specific enough to be helpful.

Comment: No time to answer. [There are some well-known limitations for Visual Studio Installer projects](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47944893/129130). Maybe have a quick look at [other, common tools](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50229840/129130) (terse summary of different deployment tools capabilities). Will look at the real question later.