# Solving Another version of program is already installed exception

Tags: c#, windows-services, windows-installer, uninstallation

I am trying to install a windows service and start it afterwards.I do not understand why after a couple of cycles (install+uninstall) i cannot install or uninstall the service anymore since i get the error:

> Another version of this product is already installed

but the service is no longer present in the `Services` window , nor is the installer present in the `Programs` section.

If i try to uninstall i get :

> Error 1001: An exception occured while uninstalling.This exception
>   will be ignored and the uninstall will continue.However the uninstall
>   might not be fully uninstalled after the uininstall is complete.

I do not understand what i am doing wrong.
I have added my project output to all custom actions:

```
-Install
-Uninstall
-Commit
-Rollback
```

How is one supposed to perform clean installs/uninstalls ?

**Installer Code**

```
    [RunInstaller(true)]
    public partial class ProjectInstaller : Installer {
        public ProjectInstaller() {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.AfterInstall += ProjectInstaller_AfterInstall;
            this.BeforeUninstall += ProjectInstaller_BeforeUninstall;
        }

        private void ProjectInstaller_AfterInstall(object sender, InstallEventArgs e) {
            StartService();
        }

        private void ProjectInstaller_BeforeUninstall(object sender, InstallEventArgs e) {
            StopService();
        }

        private void StartService() {
            Debugger.Launch();
            bool isAdmin = IsAdmin();
            if (isAdmin) {
                using (ServiceController controller = new ServiceController(serviceInstaller1.ServiceName)) {
                    controller.Start();
                }
            } else {
                ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo {
                    Verb = "runas",
                    FileName = "net",
                    Arguments = $"start {serviceInstaller1.ServiceName}"
                };
                Process.Start(info);
            }
        }

        private void StopService() {
            bool isAdmin = IsAdmin();
            if (isAdmin) {
                using (ServiceController controller = new ServiceController(serviceInstaller1.ServiceName)) {
                    controller.Stop();
                }
            } else {
                ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo {
                    Verb = "runas",
                    FileName = "net",
                    Arguments = $"stop {serviceInstaller1.ServiceName}"
                };
                Process.Start(info);
            }
        }

        private static bool IsAdmin() {
           var identity = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent();
           var princ = new WindowsPrincipal(identity);
           return princ.IsInRole(WindowsBuiltInRole.Administrator);
        }
}
```

Comment: Sounds like a racing condition to me. Give the service some time after stop and uninstall.

Comment: It has this behaviour even on the `admin` branch where you do not spawn a new process.

Comment: Do you have Service dependencies? (Services that depend on this Service or vice versa)

Comment: No i do not have.I have 2 projects.A service and a `winform` process that is opened by the the service at regular intervals, but no other dependencies.I have added both of them to `commit`,`install`,`uninstall` and `rollback` custom actions though.After i get this problem i have to delete the `Setup` project and create a new one since it won't work any other way.

Comment: If that error happens and you leave it alone for ... let's say an hour and then try again, will it consistently happen again after having waited?

Comment: Yes once it happens it remains so.Also when i try to uninstall the service i get error `1001`

Comment: Then I retract my suspicion of a racing condition. Are traces of your app left in the registry?

Comment: No there are not . I have checked in the regedit.

Comment: I upvoted your question; I do not have another idea right now, I am afraid.

Comment: Found this: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_xp-performance/installer-error-1001/a9f833b1-9b56-e011-8dfc-68b599b31bf5 -> can you check if Installer Service is (still) running? You should also check Windows Event Log. Maybe there is some new information to be found.

Comment: This may also help: https://www.wintips.org/fix-error-1001-while-uninstalling-or-installing-programs/

Comment: Is this service well behaved with start and stop when you try that manually? Are there timeout issues that are known? How long does start and stop take? What tool are you using? Visual Studio Installer Projects are known to lack service deployment features.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ***TEMP***: ***`Adding this answer, not sure it is relevant until we hear more comments from OP`***.

---

> ***Custom Actions***: MSI has built-in mechanisms to **`start`** / **`stop`** and **`install`** / **`uninstall`** services that are quite reliable. These involve populating a number of standard MSI tables. Using custom actions could trigger problems like you describe, that are hard to debug and solve.

---

***Deployment Tools***: What tool are you using?

- [Visual Studio Installer Projects have a number of severe limitations as explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47936435/visual-studio-publish-project-into-one-simple-installer/47944893#47944893) (one of which is lacking built-in support for service installation).
- The free and Open Source [WiX](https://www.wixtoolset.org) - [here is a quick start tip answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25004226/msi-vs-nuget-packages-which-are-is-better-for-continuous-delivery/25005864#25005864).
- [**Commercial tools**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50225031/windows-service-not-shown-in-add-remove-programs-under-control-panel/50229840#50229840) ([Advanced Installer](https://www.advancedinstaller.com), [Installshield](https://www.installshield.com), [PACE](https://pacesuite.com/), etc...) are excellent for most things, especially bundling prerequisites and such things.

---

***WiX Toolset***: WiX is a free, Open Source alternative, and there are several other major deployment tools you can check. Advanced Installer has some free features, but I don't think that includes service installation. Worth a test though - nice features. Installshield has no free version that I know of, but is full-featured. PACE suite is the new kid on the block. I would test them all and pick one - just 2 cents.

***WiX: Service Installation Samples***:

- Maybe see this hands on WiX-markup sample from **Rainer Stropek**: [`WiXSamples - github.com/rstropek`](https://github.com/rstropek/Samples/blob/master/WiXSamples/WindowsService/ServiceInstaller/Product.wxs). Please check the [**`ServiceControl element`**](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/servicecontrol.html).
- How to create a Windows Service MSI Installer Using WiX, this is untested by me but looks OK: https://github.com/Robs79/How-to-create-a-Windows-Service-MSI-Installer-Using-WiX
- MSI and WiX expert Chris Painter's IsWiX tutorials at: https://github.com/iswix-llc/iswix-tutorials. IsWiX is a front-end for WiX.
- And finally expert Helge Klein has published a helpful and complete WiX real-world sample: https://helgeklein.com/blog/2014/09/real-world-example-wix-msi-application-installer/