# Visual Studio Installer Project Content File References to new VS2017 Project do not work

Tags: visual-studio, windows-installer, visual-studio-setup-proje

For legacy reasons we still use the `Microsoft Visual Studio Installer Project` Extension.
In the setup project there is an project output added of type content files that points to a library project.
Via this output 3rd party stuff is included into the setup.

After migrating the library project to the new VS2017 format, the content files are empty and aren't included into the setup anymore.

Visual Studio is 2017, newest update and the installer project extension is up to date as well.

Any ideas on how to get this working?

I converted the project back to the old project format and it works again. But as the old format doesn't display NuGet references nicely, it would be cool to being able to update to the VS2017 format.

Comment: I am afraid I don't know, I don't use this tool. And for the record, here is why: [VS Installer project limitations](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47944893/129130) . Quiet here these days, let me perhaps add some alternatives: [major MSI tools](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50229840/129130). [WiX quick start](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25005864/129130). I assume you have [re-installed the tool](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioProductTeam.MicrosoftVisualStudio2017InstallerProjects) already? Did you try to insert the projects into a new solution? Etc...

Comment: Have you run a text diff on the project and solution files using [Beyond Compare](https://www.scootersoftware.com/features.php?zz=gallery) or another diff tool to look for ideas? Are there any special build steps in the project / solution?

Comment: Thank you for your comments, we know the deficites of the VS Installer and already switched some applications to WIX. But this project has a lot of files to include into the setup which was quite easy to do with the legacy installer. But it may be time now to go for WIX for this project as well...

Comment: Are you aware of the ability of WiX's `dark.exe` to decompile an existing MSI files to WiX markup? Do you have a screen shot of the before and after for this project? Is it on github.com perhaps?

Comment: No I prefer to create the WIX setup manually as we 1) already have templates for standardized setups and 2) there were so much workarounds in the legacy setup that it wouldn't make sense to inherit them .... or in other words: I am pretty sure they would blow up the whole thing! :D ;-) And it is a private project, not publicily available...

Comment: OK, could you please check - as an expert on the subject - my comments on [VS Installer project limitations](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47944893/129130). I have assembled that list from exerts in the field, and I want to know if you agree with the limitations, and if not please let us know why. I am not an experienced user of that tool, but what I have tried has not impressed me (at all). Leaves much to be desired? But has an OK GUI?