# Deploying solution with mulitple windows forms projects

Tags: deployment, visual-studio-2017, windows-forms-designer, setup-deployment

I apologize if this has been answered in another post, I can't seem to find it if it has. Anyway, I have built a back end utility for a fellow streamer friend of mine but I can't seem to figure out what I'm doing wrong when it comes to deploying it. This is a project that will be expanded on in the future, and possibly have more windows form projects. So here is what I am running into (With Pictures):

Here is my solution explorer with the projects:

[image]

When I go to build the deployment I've tried making all the projects "outputs" and got this error. Thinking it was there were too many Project Outputs I changed it to where the startup project would be the output and the others would be either source or content files. Still got these errors. Here is the File System Setup:

[image]

And when I go to run the build to create the deployment, here are the errors I receive:

[image]

[image]

I don't know/don't see what I am doing wrong here and would very much appreciate a point in the right direction. Thank you all so much in advance.

Comment: I don't use VSInstaller Projects much, [I prefer other tools](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50229840/129130) - and [here are some reasons why](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47944893/129130) (please skim for some heads-up information on limitations). That being said, it looks to me like you have a faulty installation of VS Installer Project itself. [Here is the installer for the VS2017 version I have used](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioProductTeam.MicrosoftVisualStudio2017InstallerProjects). I am honestly not sure if there is one for VS2019, try the above and see?

Comment: There could be more cleanup to do there (than simple reinstall) based on that prompt and what could be behind it (broken Visual Studio or just a missing package?). I would recommend trying on a clean install of Visual Studio 2017 or higher - perhaps on a virtual machine if you have one. Or perhaps go down the WiX route for more stability and flexibility in the future: [WiX link list long](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25004226/msi-vs-nuget-packages-which-are-is-better-for-continuous-delivery/25005864#25005864), and [short version](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63308043/129130).

Comment: Did you get this resolved?

Comment: Apologies @SteinÅsmul, my family and I were just in an car crash on May 7th so I haven't had a chance to take care of this but I will hopefully be able to work on it this weekend.

Answer (score 0):

Check your updates. I remember there is an option to review or check the status of latest updates.
I [found this article about that issue](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/setup/installing-visual-studio-2010-service-pack-1-may-prompt-for-source/) but it looks like a general error with updates or the installation

It is not too long but maybe it does not help. I hope it helps, good luck